# Angular add characters to an array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, function

I m new to angular and i'm trying to make a add character form field but i'm doing something wrong

Here is my html form with angular

```
<form class="add_character" ng-submit="characterController.addCharacter(characters)">
          <input ng-model="addCharacterCtrl.character.name" type="text">
          <input ng-model="addCharacterCtrl.character.last_name" type="text">
          <input ng-model="addCharacterCtrl.character.age" type="text">
          <textarea ng-model="addCharacterCtrl.character.history" name="" id="" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
          <input type="submit">
      </form>
```

And here is my controller with my add character function in it:

```
app.controller('CharacterController', function() {
this.characters = personages;


this.addCharacter = function(newCharacter){
  addCharacter.push(this.characters);

  this.addCharacter = [];
};
  });



  var personages = [
{
  name: 'Character',
  last_name: 'character',
  age: 21,
  history: 'character info',
},
{
  name: 'Character2',
  last_name: 'character',
  age: 44,
  history: 'character info',
}


  ];
```

And this is the error i get:

> Blockquote angular.js:13920 TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
>       at Object.addCharacter (addCharacter.js:11)
>       at fn (eval at compile (angular.js:14817), :4:394)
>       at b (angular.js:15906)
>       at e (angular.js:25885)
>       at m.$eval (angular.js:17682)
>       at m.$apply (angular.js:17782)
>       at HTMLFormElement. (angular.js:25890)
>       at Sf (angular.js:3497)
>       at HTMLFormElement.d (angular.js:3485)

I hope someone can help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As answered before the error you are getting is because you are trying to push an object into another object so change it to an array

Also your markup and code are a little overdone for what is required, here is a simplified version:

```
app.controller('CharacterController', function($scope) {

  // The initial list of characters
  // Here I declare the personages as a scope variable as I am listing them in the view (see plunker below), but you could just declare it as a normal variable
  $scope.personages = [ 
    { name: 'Character', last_name: 'character', age: 21, history: 'character info'},
    { name: 'Character2', last_name: 'character', age: 44, history: 'character info'}
  ];

  // An object to hold the new character data, use this in your form model
  $scope.newCharacter = {};

  // The form submit function which receives its model
  $scope.addCharacter = function(character) {
    $scope.personages.push(character);
  }
});

<form class="add_character" ng-submit="addCharacter(newCharacter)">
      <input ng-model="newCharacter.name" type="text">
      <input ng-model="newCharacter.last_name" type="text">
      <input ng-model="newCharacter.age" type="text">
      <textarea ng-model="newCharacter.history" name="" id="" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
      <input type="submit">
    </form>
```

Preview here:

https://plnkr.co/edit/iDVPdKm7d96XR1Sk6uQh?p=preview

Comment: it works now !! thank you  for the comments to explain the code too i learned alot!

Answer (score 2):

You have to make `addCharacter` and `Array` like [], instead of an `Object` like {}.

So write:

```
this.addCharacter = [];
```

instead of:

```
this.addCharacter = {};
```

Comment: Also: you are using "addCharacter" as a variable, a function and a param name! Use a different name for the var and a different one for the param (also the param is not used, so you might want to use it instead of push(this.addCharacter) push(myParam)

Comment: Look that code again *this.addCharacter* overwrite by function *this.addCharacter =function()*, and addCharacter is getting from html ng-submit="character.addCharacter(characters)"

Comment: @Jessep so problem is in html  "character.characters" should be pass as argument  or correct controller name with characters

Comment: im really struc now i have this now:

Comment: @Jessep firstly create the array before you start pushing stuff into it.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few things I see:

> this.addCharacter = {};

You initialized `addCharacter` as an object.

> this.addCharacter = function(addCharacter){
>         addCharacter.push(this.personages);
>       };

Next you redefine it as a function.

> addCharacter.push(this.personages);

Finally, you are trying to use Array.push to insert the character into an object. Also, you are using the same variable name in the method signature for addCharacter.